# I cannot install zoo package in R

Tags: rstudio, r.net

Hi I bump on errors during install.packages(path2zoo.tar.gz,repos=null,type="source")

It installs some other packages while trying out zoo ("zoo_1.7-14.tar.gz") produces the following error

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/savvas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'zoo' ...
** package 'zoo' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="zoo.dll" OBJECTS="coredata.o init.o lag.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'zoo'
* removing 'C:/Users/savvas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/zoo'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\savvas\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" "C:/Users/savvas/DOCUME~1/VISUAL~1/Projects/SC92B9~1/RPACKA~1/zoo_1.7-14.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/savvas/DOCUME~1/VISUAL~1/Projects/SC92B9~1/RPACKA~1/zoo_1.7-14.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

there appears the same problem if i install from command line r.exe cmd install "path2zoo.tar.gz"

any ideas?

Comment: same thing happens to forecast package :( *sigh*

Comment: You likely need to install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) -- these are needed to install many packages from sources on Windows.

Comment: does that hold even if other packages are installed properly with the same command AND the packages i cannot install from offline I can from online?

Comment: It depends on the package -- if it contains code that requires compilation (C, C++ code), or a custom configure script (requiring a bash shell) then Rtools will be required.

Comment: I downloaded rtools and installed them.No luck...This time i used RStudio instead of r.net just for checking what i get is the following error:Installing package into ‘C:/Users/savvas/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘C:/Users/savvas/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/SchedFlows V6Projects/r packages/forecast_7.3.zip’ is not available (for R version 3.3.0). I even tried to replace the package i got with download.packages with the ones downloaded by the R engine prior to automatic install.Still no luck: the error kept appearing

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies with r version. it must be set to R-3.3.2 . when r-3.3.3 is used zoo,forecast and possibly other packages remain stubbornly uninstallable from an off-line source